# Negation of a quantified statement regarding an implication.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am trying to improve my understanding of the negation of a quantified statement where the statement is an implication. I am doing a practice problem which I dont have the answer to from the textbook and would like to check if mine is right. The question is as follows:

Let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be open sentences where the domain of the variable $x$ is $T$. Which of the following implies that $(\thicksim P(x)) \implies Q(x)$ is false for some $x \in S$.

a) $P(x) \wedge Q(x)$ is false for all $x \in S$

b) $P(x)$ is true for all $x \in S$

c) $Q(x)$ is true for all $x \in S$

d) $P(x) \vee Q(x)$ is false for some $x \in S$

e) $P(x) \wedge (\thicksim Q(x))$ is false for all $x \in S$

How I approached the question is: I want to show that the statement $\exists x \in S$ s.t $(\thicksim P(x)) \implies Q(x)$ is false. Then, $$\thicksim(\exists x \in S \text{ s.t } (\thicksim P(x)) \implies Q(x)) \text{ is true }$$
$$\implies \forall x \in S \text{ s.t } (\thicksim P(x) \wedge \thicksim Q(x)) \text{ is true }$$ 
This is because $$\thicksim (\thicksim P(x) \implies Q(x))\ \ \text{is} \ \ \thicksim(\thicksim(\thicksim P(x)) \vee Q(x)$$
$$\implies \thicksim(P(x) \vee Q(x))$$
$$\implies \thicksim P(x) \wedge \thicksim Q(x)$$

Hence, the answer that I got is D. Is there any other options or am I correct here ? I would appreciate some opinions on this. Thank you

Comment: You omitted some bracketing in your 1st statement after "This is because.." It's hard to see over what part of the statement the 2nd negation is supposed to be applied.

Comment: (d) is correct. It's very easy to see why, de Morgan not required. (d) is just a paraphrase of the original statement, because $$
\neg P(x) \to Q(x) \equiv P(x) \lor Q(x)
$$

Comment: There is nothing "strange" about the negation of a quantified formula whatever. First, you have to move "inside" the leading negation sign, with (one ore more) use of the equivalences: (i) $\lnot \exists$ and $\forall \lnot$ and (ii) $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$. After that, it is only a matter of propositional logic...